# Laravel 8.9.0 Auth Sacffolding getting error Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to install latest version of Laravel 8.9.0 . larvel installed successfully. However when i try try `composer require laravel/ui:^2.4` the command I get following error

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for laravel/ui 2.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v2.4.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v8.9.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.9.0
- laravel/ui v2.4.0 requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0, v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.20.0, v7.21.0, v7.22.0, v7.22.1, v7.22.2, v7.22.3, v7.22.4, v7.23.0, v7.23.1, v7.23.2, v7.24.0, v7.25.0, v7.26.0, v7.26.1, v7.27.0, v7.28.0, v7.28.1, v7.28.2, v7.28.3, v7.28.4, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
- don't install illuminate/filesystem 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v8.9.0
```

please help

Comment: There is a reason why this does not work. You have to use version 3.0 of laravel/ui. It should work.

Comment: it is working now